# How to change target version of mac app in xamarin studio

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have created a mac app in xamarin studio community edition, While creating app i have chosen target version 10.11 (of mac/osx), but now need to change to 10.10 as per new requirements.

Please help me on how to change the target version of mac app in xamarin studio.

did lots of google but seems like very less help is available for xamarin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The target OS version is controlled via "Deployment Target" as defined within the OS-X application's `Info.plist`.

So, within `Xamarin Studio`, open `Info.plist` and change `Deployment Target`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sushi for help